# The image Icon doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities

I'm trying out the different functions of the frame and label, and the image icon doesn't show up. The code runs perfectly, but the image doesn't appear.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Label {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("momos.jpeg");
    
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.pink,10);
    
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("MOMAZOS!?!??!?!");
    label.setIcon(image);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);// set text CENTER, RIGHT OR LEFT of image icon
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);//set text TOP, CENTER OR BOTTOM of image icon
    label.setForeground(new Color(0xFF00AA));
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC,40));
    label.setIconTextGap(100);
    label.setBorder(border);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x39FF14));
    frame.add(label);

    }

}
```

I need for the image to work.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Javascript btw

Comment: With regards to this `label.setIcon(image)`. you no not have a variable called `image`. Change it to `label.setIcon(icon)`.

Answer (score 0):

[`new ImageIcon("momos.jpeg")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) searches for a file named `momos.jpeg` in the current working directory.  Are you sure you're starting the application from the directory containing `momos.jpeg`?

It is generally better to specify `URL` to a classpath resource, like:

```java
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Label.class.getResource("momos.jpeg"));
```

As long as `momos.jpeg` is in the same directory/package as the application `Label` class, it will be located no matter the current working directory.